# Jenkins emulate clean checkout for queued jobs

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have a jenkins job which uses the "Emulate Clean  Checkout" Check-out Strategy for Subversion.

The job itself runs some custom Java Code, which includes some svn actions (uses svnkit to commit some changes).

The jobs work fine if they are run periodically. However, if a build waits in the queue because it is started before the previous job is finished, it is seeming that Jenkins does not "emulate a clean checkout". The jobs are started by an svn post commit script.

The second job fails when it tries to commit, as it states the file has been modified (which it was by the previous job). If there is a gap between the jobs, it works fine.

I wonder why the Emulate Clean Checkout does not appear to work when the job is queued? Thanks for any tips.